How to have a driver control a custom property, but still have it work independently
I'm trying to set up a driver that turns on and off different eyelid meshes. I want to have a "master" driver that controls both eyelids, but also separate drivers for the left and right sides.
My original strategy was to make a custom property for each side, then use a driver to have the "master" custom property control the values, but I can't change the values of each side independently.

A driver is not something that sits on a property to read it, and based on it modify other properties. A driver is, instead, something that sits on a property to set it, based on other properties it is able to read. So a driver can't directly control 2 things. What you can do is e.g. create a scene property, where you can set a driver if needs be, and have both eyelid drivers read this property in order to decide if the lids should be open or not.
